# How to configure mail transfer for two domino servers?

Tags: ibm-domino

Currently, we do have two domino servers that are clustered. Primarily Servers 1 have the most users connected. Both server are interconnected with a leased line and I'm planning to route if mail.box in Server 1 will have 25 pending / (reach a certain condition) and route to Server 2 mail.box. So that Server 2 will be sending some mails thus helping the Server 1 tasks.

How can I make this setup?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do here. Are you talking about delivery to users with mailbox replicas on both servers? Are you talking about outbound SMTP messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea from a cluster is normally load balancing. So if you wish that Server 1 and Server 2 handle both the outgoing emails from the users, then you need to split the workload on both servers. BUT that means also that both servers will accept users on it. That means you might end up with more traffic on the leased line! However for the config above you should have a look on the following notes.ini:

[Server_Availability_Threshold](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/23-clustering/2168-serveravailabilitythreshold.html) - By setting this value for each server in a cluster, you determine how the workload is distributed among cluster members.

However this required some ... say advanced tweaking ... as the value must be set according to the server hardware. That means if server 1 is much more powerful then server 2 you might end up with different values for both servers to produce a +/- 50 workload split.

*Note:*
*If you use Server_Availability_Threshold=0 on server2 and Server_Availability_Threshold=100 on server1 you could build a kind of failover environment. However some of your applications might not work with that system when they use hardcoded application names! So please be carefully with that config!*

Another idea to speed up the routing would be to use multiple mail.box files. You could configure that in the server config (not in the notes.ini). I personally have never used more then 3 mail.boxes on a server. Most servers should be fine with 2 mail.box files.

Another idea to speed up the router process is to fine tune it. For example you could change the [MailMaxMessageQueue](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/17-router/1236-mailmaxmessagequeue.html).

Comment: Currently, we have setup two mail.box already and glad to hear that. Since it will be critical to change server_availability_threshold, i would first opt to optimize the mail.box as you suggested. Thank you once again Sir BastianW.